# How to transfer items from treeview to richtextbox?

Tags: c#, foreach, treeview, richtextbox

I used foreach to solve this problem. I have never encountered an error. But it sends the items wrong.

I want to do it like this: roots: 1,2,3 and child nodes: a,b,c,d,e,f. The RichTextBox will look like this: 1->a->b->2->c->d->3->e->f.

here is the code:

```
foreach (TreeNode root in treeView1.Nodes)
        {

            foreach (TreeNode child in root.Nodes)
            {
               richTextBox1.SelectedText = (root.Text + "->" + child.Text);
            }


        }
```

But it looks like this: 1->a1->b2->c2->d3->e3->f.

Where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is that for every root->child pair, you are writing that value the end of the `TextBox`. This will give you 1->a|1->b|2->c|2->d|3->e|3->f at each iteration in your for loop. When you remove the pipes and combine all iterations, you get 1->a1->b2->c2->d3->e3->f, as you posted. (This could have been found with step through debugging).

A better option is to convert your `TreeView` to a string first, and then add it to the `TextBox`. Your problem is a perfect example for using [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). You will first need to make a method to convert your tree into a string, then write that string to your textbox. This also handles a `TreeView` with more than two deep.

```
private string TreeViewToString(TreeView tv, string delimiter) {
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (TreeNode node in tv.Nodes) {
        TraverseNodes(node, delimited, result);
    }

    if (result.Length < delimiter.Length) {
        return result.ToString();
    } else {
        return result.ToString(0, result.Length - delimiter.Length); 
    }             
}

// recursive part
private void TraverseNodes(TreeNode node, string delimiter, StringBuilder result) {
    result.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", node.Text, delimiter);      // add node to string

    foreach (TreeNode subNode in node.Nodes) {
        TravserseNodes(subNode, delimiter, result);           // recurse into nodes children
    }
}
```

There are many ways to accomplish this but here is one way and it should be fairly straight forward (if you understand recursion).